# "So bin ich" vs "Ich auch"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> Sie ist glücklich. So bin ich.
>   Sie ist glücklich. Ich auch.
>
> Sie ist gestorben. So bin ich.
>   Sie ist gestorben. Ich auch.

Hat "So bin ich" dieselbe Bedeutung wie "Ich auch" in diesem Kontext (me too)?

Oder bedeutet das eher "That's how I am"?

Ich habe ein Gedicht geschrieben und habe "So bin ich" am Ende jeder Strophe wiederholt. Ich könnte stattdessen "Ich auch" sagen, aber wenn es passt, wäre es besser. Ist es möglich oder muss ich "Ich auch" sagen?

Comment: "so bin ich" als wörtliche Übersetzung von "so am I" funktioniert im Deutschen nicht.

Comment: @Ingmar Ob es eine Übersetzung für "so am I" sein soll, steht nirgends. Aber "So bin ich" ist im Deutschen sehr wohl möglich, vor allen Dingen in einem Gedicht, wo es sogar besser als "Ich auch" klingt.

Comment: Hm. "So bin ich" ist natürlich möglich, dann aber als Entsprechung von "that's the way I am". Wenn damit "ich auch" gemeint sein soll, hielte ich das für unrichtig, künstlerische Freiheit hin oder her.

Comment: Ich gebe zu, im ersten Satz ist es wirklich problematisch, das es sich dabei um ein Vollverb handelt. Im zweiten Satz ist es aber ein Hilfsverb, und da sehe ich absolut keine Einwände.

Comment: "So bin ich" klingt für mich wie Englisch mit deutschen Wörtern, hölzern. Wer Englisch kann, merkt sofort, hier hat einer, der kein richtiges Deutsch, kann vom Englischen Wort für Wort ins Deutsche übersetzt. "So bin ich" sagt kein Mensch.

Comment: *Wie das Land, so das Jever.* Nach so vielen Downvotes in den Antworten stellt sich mir die Frage, ob es je nach Region unteschiedliche Antworten geben könnte.

Comment: @c.p. Nein, denn in diesem Beispiel weist das *so* auf die Konstruktion mit *wie* hin, es handelt sich, im Gegensatz zum Fragenbeispiel, um einen Vergleich. Ohne *wie* bzw. *auch* geht hier gar nichts, und genau das ist der Fall im Fragenbeispiel.

Comment: @user13798 Wäre es für dich in Ordnung, die Frage außerhalb eines dichterischen Kontexts gestellt zu sehen?

Comment: "Wie das Land (ist), so (ist auch) das Jever" - "Das Land ist schön, (und) so (auch) das Jever" – "Sie ist glücklich. (Und) so bin (auch) ich". # Sowohl "und" als auch "auch" können ausgelassen werden. Ellipse nennt sich das. Hatte ich in der ersten Fassung meiner Antwort schon geschrieben (und inzw. per Rollback auch wieder hergestellt). Ist alles im Deutschen möglich, insb. in einem Gedicht, aber auch in der Umgangssprache. Und es hat auch nichts mit dem "wie" zu tun, wie die Ergänzung mit den Verben zeigt.

Comment: Ich würde "so bin ich" nicht als "ich auch" verstehen, hätte aber stattdessen diesen Vorschlag: "so auch ich". Damit wird klar was gemeint ist (dass Du auch glücklich oder gestorben bist), und es klingt etwas poetischer als "ich auch".

Answer (score 10):

Dass "false friends", d.h. rein wörtliche Übersetzungen ohne Bedacht des jeweiligen idiomatischen Umfelds, englischen Sprechern bzw. Übersetzern passieren, ist nicht verwunderlich. Eher, dass sie unter Deutschsprachigen so häufig sind.

"So am I" kann ***nicht*** mit "So bin ich" übersetzt werden. Die einfachste Übersetzung ist:

> *Ich auch.*

Alternative:

> *Das bin ich auch.*

Wäre "so bin ich" für "so am I" möglich, müsste man auch "so habe ich" für "so have I" sagen können, woran das Problem noch viel deutlicher wird. "So" kann nicht in dieser Funktion verwendet werden.

Eine passende Übersetzung von "So bin ich" wäre ungefähr tatsächlich "That's how I am", aber der deutsche Satz funktioniert in dieser Formulierung nur in einem gesprochenen Kontext mit Betonung auf "bin". In einem Text würde man eine Ausgleichspartikel dazusetzen, z.B. "eben":

> So bin ich eben!

"So" weist auf eine Eigenschaft hin und macht das Verb *sein* automatisch zum Hauptverb:

> So bin ich: freigebig, lebenslustig und gesellig. Das können hier alle
>   bestätigen.

Comment: Tote sprechen zu lassen ist ja jetzt nicht so weit hergeholt: ein toter Erzähler z.B. oder ein wiedergeborenes Liebespaar (etwa [Hawkman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkman) and [Hawkgirl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkgirl)). +1 für den Vergleich mit *haben*.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Das stimmt natürlich, aber für ein simples Grammatikbeispiel hätte sich vielleicht auch etwas Herkömmlicheres finden lassen ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> So bin ich.

entspricht dem englischen *That's how I am/That's the way I am* und kann nicht im Sinne von „Ich auch“ verwendet werden, so wie das im Englischen üblich ist (*So am I*).

Es ist eine grammatikalische Antwort auf „Wie bin ich?“, was für „Ich auch“ nicht der Fall ist.

Siehe auch die im Duden gelisteten Bedeutungen/Verwendungen von [„so“](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_derartig_solch_genauso_etwa).

Answer (score 1):

Offenbar eine nicht so triviale Frage wie gedacht …

Ich gehöre zum ablehnenden Lager – zunächst intuitiv, aber nachdem sogar Takkat diese Konstruktion "durchaus" für zulässig hält, mache ich mir natürlich doch Gedanken.

Soweit ich sehe, sind die Bedeutungsfelder von "so" im Deutschen und im Englischen nicht deckungsgleich.
Hier relevant ist die englische Bedeutung/Verwendung im Sinne von "ebenso"/"ebenfalls". 
Im Deutschen ist dies zwar ähnlich möglich, allerdings immer mit der zusätzlich implizierten Qualifikation, also eher in Richtung "dermaßen"/"ebenso [Adjektiv]".

Den Einsatz als vergleichende Konjunktion (Takkats Argument) sehe ich im vorliegenden Fall nicht gegeben – es wird ja nicht verglichen, *wie* tot die beiden Herrschaften sind. So wie beabsichtigt würde es meiner Meinung nach allenfalls mit "das" und einem nachgestellten "auch" funktionieren: Sie ist tot und das bin ich auch.

Die Argumentation mit der Unterscheidung von "ist" als Voll- bzw. Hilfsverb (Em1) verstehe ich offenbar nicht so richtig, weil ich genau den umgekehrten Eindruck habe. Mir scheint die erste Version ("glücklich") weniger unakzeptabel als die zweite ("gestorben"). 
Wenn ich darüber nachdenke, vermute ich, dass es wieder mit dem Bedeutungsspektrum von "so" zu tun hat. "Ich bin ebenso sehr glücklich [wie sie]" finde ich ok, "ich bin ebenso sehr gestorben [wie sie]" geht nicht.
Insgesamt antwortet "so" für mich auf die Frage "wie ist X?" – im vorliegenden Kontext scheint aber die Frage "was ist X?" beantwortet zu werden. Und das kommt mir unrichtig vor.

EDIT zur Ellipsen-Interpretation:
Grundsätzlich sind Ellipsen natürlich zulässige und oft ausgesprochen elegante, "schöne" Stilmittel. Das Problem im vorliegenden Fall liegt für mich darin: Eine Ellipse darf die Aussage des Satzes nicht verändern. Wenn ich nun die fragliche Konstruktion als Ellipse interpretiere, wie in Takkats Beispiel

> Sie ist glücklich, so [wie] ich [es] bin.

dreht sich die Aussage um. Im vollständigen Satz dient der Sprecher als Referenz dafür, zu beschreiben, wie "sie" drauf ist. In der verkürzten Version (und in der originalen Frage) ist "sie" die Referenz dafür, zu beschreiben, wie der Sprecher drauf ist. Ich finde, das sollte bei einer einfachen sprachlichen Umformung nicht passieren.
Und letztlich bin ich nicht sicher, ob

> Sie ist glücklich, so ich bin.

tatsächlich das Gleiche ist wie

> Sie ist glücklich, so bin ich.

Nach wie vor kommt mir die Sache eigenartig vor und ich kann die Konstruktion nicht befriedigend in ihre Bestandteile zerlegen.

[Vermutlich sollte das eher ein Kommentar sein – fürs erste Brainstorming kam mir aber das Antwortformat praktischer vor, sorry... Werde diese Antwort löschen, wenn nicht mehr in Arbeit...]

Comment: Nur als weiterer Anstoß: würde man sagen "Sie ist glücklich, so wie ich." oder "Sie ist glücklich, so wie ich **es bin.**" wäre es auch deiner Ansicht nach richtig, oder? In beiden Fällen wird 'so' zusammen mit 'wie' vergleichend benutzt. Nun kann man aber durchaus elliptisch einiges weglassen, im letzten Fall das "es bin." Für mein Sprachempfinden (Toscho und Em1 teilen das offenbar) kann man insb. poetisch (!) doch auch "wie es" weglassen und landet dann bei der Formulierung des Gedichts. Ich halte es für sehr verwegen, zu behaupten dies sei falsch (nur deshalb meine Antwort übrigens).

Comment: @Takkat Das *so* weist in diesem Fall einfach auf die Konstruktion mit *wie*, es bedeutet noch immer nicht *auch*.

Comment: @Takkat "Sie ist so glücklich wie ich" würde man am ehesten sagen, oder "sie ist glücklich und ich ebenso". "Sie ist glücklich, so bin ich" aber nicht, weil "so" nicht allein für die Aussage des Hauptsatzes "sie ist glücklich" einstehen kann. Als Ersatz für "wie" nur, wenn man das "bin" zwingend weglässt, als Verkürzung: "Sie ist glücklich, so auch ich" (wie es auch eines deiner Beispiele zeigt -> "Sie ist glücklich, wie ich auch"). Ganz deutlich mit Verstärkung: "Sie ist glücklich, also auch ich".

Comment: Die Diskussion scheint sich mittlerweile totgelaufen zu haben, trotzdem: @Takkat: ich hab mal über Deinen Einwand nachgedacht - siehe Edit

Answer (score 0):

Eine idiomatische Wendung ist es nicht. Ist der Leser des Englischen mächtig, wird er es als Anglizismus empfinden. Kennt er Englisch nicht, kann er sehr wohl verirrt sein, und sich fragen "Ja wie denn bloß?".

Die Poesie steht aber ein Stück weit über dererlei Dingen. Ein Dichter kann die Sprache in allerlei Richtungen biegen und es ist am Leser es zu verstehen und gut oder schlecht zu finden. Wer Lyrik mag, wird die Zeilen verstehen und evtl sogar elegant finden.

Für wer immer mit Lyrik nix anfangen kann,
es wird klingen komisch.

Comment: Stimmt schon (vgl. experimentelle Literatur), aber die Formulierung der Frage zielt vorwiegend auf eine Beantwortung im Kontext der Standardsprache ab. Und auch wenn dem nicht so wäre, würde es ob des Formats dieser Site immer noch mehr Sinn machen, die dichterische Freiheit zumindest primär zu vernachlässigen.

Answer (score -3):

Man kann das `So bin ich.` durchaus mit derselben Bedeutung wie `Ich auch` lesen, aber man muss es nicht so lesen. Man könnte es durchaus auch so lesen, dass das lyrische Ich derartige Eigenschaften hat, dass das lyrische Sie glücklich bzw. gestorben ist. Die erste Variante entsteht durch Betonung von `ich`. Die zweite Variante entsteht durch Betonung von `so` (oder `bin`).

Answer (score -4):

#### 'so' als Konjunktionaladverb

Man kann durchaus einen vergleichenden Nebensatz auch mit **so** verbinden, dann als sogenanntes [Konjunktionaldverb](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Klasse/Konjunktional.html). In diesem Fall sollte der Nebensatz mit einem Komma eingeleitet werden, wenn man diese Verwendung deutlich machen möchte:

> Sie ist glücklich, so bin ich.
> Sie ist gestorben, so bin ich.

Man kann aber auch auf eine unumstrittene Version zurückgreifen, falls man Sorge hat, dass man nicht verstanden wird:

> Sie ist glücklich, so wie ich.
> Sie ist gestorben, so wie ich.

Comment: Der Satz muss nicht mit einem Komma eingeleitet werden. Ein Satz darf ja auch mit "Und" oder "Oder" beginnen. Und das aus gutem Grund. So darf dann auch "So bin ich" nach einem Punkt stehen.

Comment: @Em1: man muss da schon ein Komma setzen, wenn klar sein soll, dass man nicht etwas anderes meint ("that's how I am" wäre mit Punkt, wie andere bereits richtig festgestellt haben). Im Gedicht kann man aber sowieso andere Regeln gelten lassen und ich halte das auch mit Punkt nicht für missverständlich.

Comment: Unmissverständlich ist es im Kontext allemal. Egal, was für ein Satzzeichen man verwendet.

Comment: @Em1 Ich bitte widerholt um externe Belege. Nur weil du etwas gerne im Deutschen haben möchtest/sagen können möchtest, ist es noch lange nicht Realität. Falls diese Verwendung tatsächlich regional existiert, wäre es gut, dies in den Antworten anzumerken. Aber auch dafür lassen sich Belege (nicht) finden – andernfalls bleibt es ein persönlicher Wunsch (was keine Schande ist, es ist lediglich wünschenswert, so objektiv wie möglich zu bleiben).

Comment: @Grantwalzer Bis vor 1h hätte ich es nicht als "regional" betrachtet. Takkat und Toscho, die prinzipiell "so bin ich" auch als richtig ansehen, leben woanders als ich. So ist es also mindestens "überregional". Googlen tue ich mir schwer, weil 99% der Sätze eben nicht "so bin ich." lauten (und Google kann leider keine Satzzeichen). Und mein "persönlicher Wunsch" entspricht schlicht einer Tatsache. Es wird (wenngleich in Relation auch selten) verwendet. Und es überrascht mich wirklich sehr, dass ich im Duden kein Beispiel gefunden habe.

Comment: @Em1 „Tatsachen“ lassen sich in irgendeiner Form belegen/argumentieren. Martin Schwehla z.B. hat einen einleuchtenden Vergleich gezogen. Um einer praktisch nicht auffindbaren Konstruktion „Überregionalität“ zuschreiben zu können, müssten diese Antworten zumindest so etwas wie „Das wird bei uns so gesagt“ oä enthalten. Vielleicht ist es derart schwierig einzusehen, weil das allgeimeinste aller Verben verwendet wurde. Hier noch ein um ein Fünkchen spezifischerer Vergleich: I can fly and so can you. != Ich kann fliegen und so kannst du.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Schönes Beispiel. Nur dass ich das wieder gegenteilig sehe. Aber weiter darüber zu diskutieren macht echt keinen Sinn. Das ist mir langsam echt zu doof. Ich beende das hiermit, und "so solltest du" ;)

Comment: Und noch eine Korrektur. Zitat:  "... sollte der Nebensatz..". In den ersten beiden Beispielen gibt es keinen Nebensatz. Nur zwei Hauptsätze.

Comment: @Emanuel: deshalb auch "wenn man" das so machen möchte (ich würde sowieso "...,so wie ich" bevorzugen.

Comment: @Takkat... mir geht's um die Terminologie. Es ist genausowenig ein Nebensatz wie "Se ist glücklich". Ob da ein Komma ist, oder ein Punkt, ist egal. Es sind zwei Hauptsätze.

Answer (score -5):

In beiden Fällen sehe ich keine Probleme "So bin ich" zu verweden. Das gilt für die Umgangssprache und insbesondere für Gedichte. Wie im Kommentar angemerkt, wirkt es im ersten Beispiel daher problematisch, weil es ein Vollverb ist.
Es handelt sich hier aber konkret um eine **Ellipse** von

> Sie ist glücklich. Und so(=glücklich) bin auch ich.
>   Sie ist glücklich. So bin ich.

Gerade im Gedicht ist es kein Problem dies zu "So bin ich" zu kürzen, zumal es dann übereinstimmend mit den anderen Zeilen ist.

> Sie ist gestorben. So bin ich.

Hier ist es ein Hilfsverb und ich sehe keine Gründe "So bin ich" in Frage zu stellen.

Es ist richtig, dass man in der Umgangssprache wohl (fast) immer zu "Ich auch" greifen würde, nicht zuletzt weil "So bin ich" sehr hochgestochen wirkt.

Comment: Das funktioniert im Deutschen so einfach nicht. Referenzen wären praktisch.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Mein Sprachgefühl. Und mindestens zwei weitere Personen stimmen mir zumindest zu, dass "So bin ich" OK ist, wenngleich auch mit anderen Argumenten. Und nicht zuletzt reden wir hier über Poesie, und nicht über formelles Deutsch. Spätestens da (also Poesie) ist so ziemlich alles erlaubt. PS: Referenzen das es nicht geht, wären genau so schön. Da das Thema aber sehr dünn behandelt sein dürfte, wird es schwer sein, welche zu finden.

Comment: So eine besondere Verwendungsmöglichkeit wäre im Duden gelistet – ist sie aber nicht. Übersetzungen ins Englische mit *too* oder *also* würden ([etwa hier](http://www.dict.cc/?s=so)) angeboten werden. Ein Gedicht oder sonst ein ästhetisch-kreatives Werk, welches zu dieser Bedeutung greift, würde reichen.

Comment: Im Gedichtskontext wären mir jetzt zwei Interpretationen für "Sie ist gestorben. So bin ich." eingefallen und keine davon läuft auf "Ich bin auch gestorben." hinaus. NUMMER 1: "Sie ist tot. So bin ich halt; ihr wisst doch, dass ich ein Mörder bin." Hier klingt "So bin ich." wie eine nachträgliche Entschuldigung dafür, dass sie tot ist. NUMMER 2: "Sie ist gestorben. Das ist der Grund dafür, dass ich existiere." Hier lese ich das "so" als "also" und das "bin" als "existiere". (Hey, das ist 'n Gedicht, da kommt sowas häufiger vor.)

Comment: @Grantwalzer Takkat hat in seiner Antwort ein sehr gutes Beispiel genannt: "Fritz ist in Klasse 2b, so ist Klaus". Anstatt "so ist Klaus" könnte da auch "so bin ich" stehen.

Comment: Ist für mich nicht idiomatisch. "Ebenso Klaus" geht, aber "so ist Klaus" klingt einfach falsch.

Comment: @Ingmar Kann sein, dass man sowas in Österreich nicht sagen. Aber es existiert. Und ich hasse es, wenn man sagt: "Das sagt man bei uns nicht, also ist die Antwort falsch". Man muss auch mal über den Tellerrand hinausschauen.

Comment: @Em1 Du scheinst sehr gut Englisch sprechen zu können – ich denke, das beeinflusst dich, denn auch in Deutschland sagt man das nicht. Beispiel 1) Die Hervorhebung von *so* macht es nicht magisch zu einem *auch*. Beispiel 2) ist einfach kein Deutsch. Gleichsam Beispiel 3) und bei Beispiel 4) weist *so* auf die Konstruktion mit *wie*, und hier geht es schlichtweg nicht um Vergleiche.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Kannst du das bitte meinem Englischlehrer sagen. Ich hatte immer ne 5 in Englisch :( – Im Ernst, inwiefern bezieht es sich im Beispiel 3 auf "wie"? "Ich liebe dich wie du mich", oder was? Das ist das einzige was mir einfällt, aber das ist nicht die Aussage von "So ich dich", sondern "Das trifft auch auf mich zu". – Ach, ich wollte ja eigentlich nix mehr sagen. Never mind.

Comment: Das war schlecht formuliert von mir – ich meinte, dass sich Beispiel drei gleichsam falsch wie Beispiel zwei anhört.

Comment: @Grantwalzer OK. Verstanden. Naja, also wir bleiben dabei, dass wir uns da nicht einig werden. Einige sagen es ist richtig, einige sagen es ist falsch. Ich glaube alle haben recht.

Comment: Gut möglich, dass diese Verwendung in ein paar Jahren tatsächlich Eingang in die deutsche Sprache findet – ich würde sie willkommen heißen. Per Status quo ist sie jedoch schlichtweg falsch, und das spiegelt sich auch Gott sei Dank (um der Besucher dieses Forums willen) in den Votes wider.

Comment: @Em1 Wo habe ich mich geweigert über den Tellerrand zu schauen? Ich sagte _für mich_ nicht idiomatisch. Dem ist nichts hinzuzufügen. Kann sein, dass man das in Deutschland so sagt, _für mich_ klingt es eben falsch.

Comment: Das Beispiel mit "wie du mir" mit dem Beispiel "ich liebe dich" zu vergleichen, ist mehr als wackelig. Auf was bezieht sich denn das "so" bitte in dem Satz mit "Liebe"? Auf das Verb? Nach der Logik müsste dann auch folgendes funktionieren. "Ich mache etwas." "So ich."... wohl kaum. -1